# Laravel Excel::download returns blank file when records are too much

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have a functionality for downloading reports for orders in my DB based on a given period.
I am using `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"`.

Laravel version is `5.5.*`

Here's some code:

Controller:

```
// ...Filtering orders from DB

Log::debug('Report baskets: '.$baskets->count());

return Excel::download(new ByStatusv2Export($baskets),
    'finance_report_v2_' . now()->format('Y-m-d_U') . '.xlsx');
```

The ByStatusv2Export class:

```
class ByStatusv2Export extends DefaultValueBinder implements ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting, FromView, WithCustomValueBinder
{
    protected $baskets;

    public function __construct($baskets)
    {
        $this->baskets = $baskets;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('warehouse::admin.export.financev2', ['baskets' => $this->baskets]);
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'D' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'J' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
        ];
    }

    public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($cell->getCoordinate(), 'B')) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($cell->getCoordinate(), 'E')) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($cell->getCoordinate(), 'F')) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($cell->getCoordinate(), 'G')) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($cell->getCoordinate(), 'J')) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        // else return default behavior
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
    }
}
```

I checked many checkpoints with `dd($baskets)` and it looks fine everywhere - **The correct records are actually fetched from the database.**
I have confirmed that the class receives the data and that the baskets property is set correctly.

Here is the financev2.blade.php:

```
<html>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Статус</td>
        <td>Продукт</td>
        <td>Доставна цена</td>
        <td>Продажна цена</td>
        <td>IMEI</td>
        <td>Дата на поръчка</td>
        <td>Дата на завършване</td>
        <td>Доставчик </td>
        <td>Метод на плащане </td>
        <td>Платено </td>
        <td>Име на клиент </td>
        <td>Фирма получател</td>
        <td>Фирма</td>
        <td>Номер на поръчка</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($baskets as $basket)
        @foreach ($basket->products as $product)
            @foreach ($product->imei as $imei)
                <tr>
                    <td>@lang('warehouse::admin.'.$basket->status)</td>
                    <td>{{ $product->product->title ?? '-' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $imei->delivery_price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ !empty($imei->sale_price) ? $imei->sale_price : $product->getSellPrice($product->option_group_id) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $imei->imei }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $basket->ordered_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $basket->finished_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ !empty($basket->delivery_service) ? trans('warehouse::admin.'.$basket->delivery_service) : 'Rapido' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ trans('warehouse::admin.'.$basket->payment_method) }}</td>
                    @if($basket->isPaid())
                        <td>Да</td>
                    @else
                        <td>Не</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{ $basket->getContactName() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $basket->getCompanyName() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $basket->getSenderCompanyName() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $basket->database_id }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

**The problem is:**

- on the production server, when I select a larger period of time (let's say one month) **it returns an empty excel sheet** (this problem was not occuring before). With smaller periods (like 2-3 days sometime even a week it works).
- **On local with the same DB it works fine.**
- One thing I noticed is that when it fails it downloads the file very fast. Usually it takes some time process the data, but it seems like it gives up before even running through the foreachs in the blade file.

It does not record any errors in the logs.
I compared the php.ini configuration on both local and prod server and synced the values of params like memory_limit, max_execution_time etc. but still no effect.

Comment: There must a memory threshold that triggers the process abortion, that's why it is faster.

Comment: How many lines does it mean exactly? xls and xlsx does have a limit of lines. Csv does not.

Comment: @MátyásGrőger I am currently able to download around 1040 rows of export. One date larger (should around 100-200 more) and the problems begins.

Comment: You can try generating excel in a queue and send them by email attachment

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko not a very relevant idea. I want all the records in one sheet. The people that are going to use the data from the sheet are doing it slower and less efficient if there are seperate files.

Comment: You can do all  this in a single file while using  queue for better performance